# How to allow access to users folder in firebase storage for an admin account

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am currently developping a serverless app using Firebase,

One issue I ran into is having "admin" accounts, I solved it by having an admin boolean in the realtime database that is checked by rule to allow global read.
However I also need this users to access all files stored on storage. Currently my rules are setup so that each users can read from it's own folder but this is based on user ID and doesn't allow that admin system.
Is there any way around that ?

Here are the rules I use for storage:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, in Cloud Storage security rules to read data stored in the Realtime Database (nor data stored in Firestore).

One possible solution is to use some [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), to assign an "Admin" role to the corresponding users. You can use the claim in the Cloud Storage security rules as well as in the databases security rules.

Comment: Looks like custom claims is going to be the way to go, thanks!